# AutoMapper - Passing in parameters for mapping of associated objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm mapping customer objects using Automapper. Each customer object has an array of Address objects.

During the mapping of the AdressType property, I'm would like to use a variable that has been passed in during the Mapper.Map invocation on the Customer object. The variable hasn't anything to do with the Customer object itself but is relevant in the mapping of the associated address objects.
Passing in a function that is using the variable to map the AdressType property is also fine. Is there a way of doing such a thing?

I'm not sure how to call ForMember for the mapping of the AddressType property. The variable gets created just before I map the customer object. It's not as easy as calling a method in ForMember to map AddressType. I'll have to make use of a variable that is created along the way.

As I'm typing this, I'm thinking to make the variable static so it can be returned by a static method which can be used in ForMember. But at second thought I don't think I can get away with this as the application is actually a WCF service. The variable is different for every request coming in.

I'm using AutoMapper 4.2.1 in a VS2012 solution.
Any thoughts, pointers, life lines?

```
    myVariable = ...
    var customerDest = mapper.Map<CustomerSource, CustomerDestination>(someCustomerSource, <my variable or function>);


    // Configuration of AutoMapper
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
      cfg.CreateMap<AddressSource, AddressDestination>()
        .ForMember(m => m.AddressType, 
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => MapAddressType(src.AddressType, <my variable>) ???


    public class Customer 
    { 
        public Address[] Addresses { get; set; }
    }

    public Address
    {
      public string AdresType { get; set; }
    }
```

**Solution:**

```
cfg.CreateMap<AddressSource, AddressDestination>()
                    .ForMember(m => m.AddressType, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(
                        (resolutionResult, source) => 
                            {
                                var addressType = (resolutionResult.Context.SourceValue as AddressSource).AddressType;
                                var myVariable = resolutionResult.Context.Options.Items["myVariable"] as Dictionary<string, SomeType>;
                                return DoStuff(addressType, myVariable);
                            }));



var dest = mapper.Map<CustomerDestination>(customerSource,
                        opt => opt.Items["myVariable"] = myVariable);
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366661/passing-around-values-to-an-automapper-type-converter-from-outside

Comment: Even though I'm on an older version (4.2.1), it did give me enough pointers to solve it.